# OpenAPI сайта dadata.ru

Tags: openapi

Есть dadata.ru, у них есть [API](https://dadata.ru/api/). Где можно найти схему в формате OpenAPI (Swagger), может быть не официальную?

Comment: Вопрос, зачем? https://github.com/hflabs/dadata-csharp

Comment: @こきん она нужна чтобы обучить файрвол не блокировать запросы.